# AppleScript for Numbers - iteration target wrong or subRange is mistyped?

Tags: applescript

For my first AppleScript, I need to take a range of selected columns and add a new column after each individual column in the range.  I named it "Add Interstitial Columns".

My logic is:

```
-- Activate Numbers and get the current selection as a table
-- Iterate over the columns property of the selectedTable and
-- create a new range with each column and
-- ask the column to add column after
-- loop
-- exit
```

I've obviously done it wrong, but as it's my first foray into AppleScript the reasons it's wrong completely escape me. What's happening is I'm getting 3 new columns after my row header column, and then it bails with "can't create more columns".

I'm thinking that the datatype of `subRange` may not be a range? Anyway, here's the code:

```swift
-- Activate Numbers and get the current selection as a table
tell application "Numbers"
    activate
    try
        if not (exists document 1) then error number 1000
        tell document 1
            try
                tell active sheet
                    set the selectedTable to ¬
                        (the first table whose class of selection range is range)
                end tell
            on error
                error number 1001
            end try

            tell selectedTable
                
                -- Iterate over the columns property of the selectedTable and
                repeat with i from 1 to the count of columns
                    -- create a new range with each column and
                    set subRange to column i of selectedTable
                    tell subRange
                        add column after last column
                    end tell
                end repeat
                -- loop
            end tell
            -- exit
        end tell
    on error errorMessage number errorNumber
        if errorNumber is 1000 then
            set alertString to "MISSING RESOURCE"
            set errorMessage to ¬
                "Please create or open a document before running this script."
        else if errorNumber is 1001 then
            set alertString to "SELECTION ERROR"
            set errorMessage to ¬
                "Please select a table before running this script."
        else
            set alertString to "EXECUTION ERROR"
        end if
        if errorNumber is not -128 then
            display alert alertString message errorMessage buttons {"Cancel"}
        end if
        error number -128
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the downsides of *try* statements is that they obscure what the script is doing — or not doing. Sometimes it is easier to work things out and then implement them.

Not sure what is inhibiting your script but one likely issue is that as you add each column, the numbers get out of sync, e.g. what was column 2 becomes column 3 after you add the first column. Your loop doesn't seem to take that into account.

One alternative approach is to reverse the processing order.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell table 1 of active sheet of document 1
        
        set colList to columns -- e.g. columns (1, 2, 3, 4}
        set revColList to reverse of colList -- e.g. columns {4, 3, 2, 1}
        
        repeat with eachCol in revColList
            add column after eachCol
        end repeat
        
    end tell
end tell
```